# How to tell that there is no result of a function with return value?

Tags: c++, function, error-handling, coding-style, return-type

I have a short question. Given a function which returns an object of a class as result, what should I return if there is no result (say because an index is out of range)? I could return a new "empty" object but how can I point out that there was no successful calculation?

I suppose there is a common approach.

Comment: throw an exception http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: If an error has occurred why not throw an exception ?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets. Thanks, I hadn't used that before. If you would write that as a short answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @sharethis added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw an exception when values don't match expected results.

A tutorial can be found at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions

An exception works with a try and catch principle.

A program "tries" to execute code.
If something unexpected happens the executed code "throws" an object, variable or whatever and this will be caught.
In the catch statement you can place code what should happen if the unexpected has happened.

Just follow the tutorial.

Comment: Just to point out, you can save yourself and everyone else a lot of pain by only throwing std::exception and subclasses as they provide a single way to get a meaning full error string `what()`. Throwing plain int char values has to be the worst thing that can be done.

Comment: But throwing 0xDEAD or 0xBABE is fun @josefx

Answer (score 13):

The common approach in C++ is either to throw an exception or to use some wrapper like [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

An exception should be thrown if it is some kind of error, the `boost::optional`-approach is more appropriate if it is a valid use-case of your function to return an empty result. One example that comes to mind is SQL's NULL. `boost::optional` turned out quite handy in our codebase.

Comment: As a side note, in some more or less recent video I saw *Alexandrescu*  propose an `Exceptional` type (was it called that way?), which is in the end a `boost::optional` with the second option not being an empty value but an exception, and thus would be conceptually appropriate to be used for error cases (in constrast to a plain `boost::optional`). Otherwise sound reasoning +1.

Comment: Yep, seen that too and it's call `Expected<T>`. The reason I didn't mention it is that I still consider it both *experimental and advanced*. But it's a good teaser for advanced readers, so here's a [link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C).

Answer (score 3):

Going by the philosophy of the [vector::at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) method throw `out_of_range` exception if possible.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the semantics of the operation is.

If an *error* occurred, you should definitely **throw an exception**:

```
#include <stdexcept> // Necessary for standard exceptions

X foo()
{
    ...
    if (/* something goes wrong... */)
    {
        // There may be a more appropriate exception class. You could
        // also derive your own exception class from std::exception...
        throw std::logic_error("Whatever!"); 
    }

    ...
}

...

try
{
    X x = foo();
    // Work with x...
}
catch (std::logic_error const& e) // Catch what is appropriate...
{
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

If returning a no-value does not denote an error condition, you could use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). Alternatively, provided you can create an "empty" object of type `X`, you could think of returning a pair whose second member is a `bool` flag that tells whether the first member is a valid object or not, as below:

```
std::pair<X, bool> foo();

...

bool valid;
X x;
std::tie(x, valid) = foo();
if (valid)
{
    // Use x...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Boost.Optional.

Comment: It is worth noting that the `std::pair` solution only makes sense if you can create an empty value of type `X`. And then, sometimes the emptiness of the return value can be used instead of the `bool`.

Comment: @rodrigo: I agree with the first sentence (will edit, thank you), while I would not like returning an empty object *only*: by looking at the function's signature, the `pair<X, bool>` already gives me a hint that `X` might be empty. But I guess it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about erroneous situation, throwing an exception is proper solution.

```
#include<exception>

Object * GenerateObject(int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw std::out_of_range("i");

    return new Object(i);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
     try
     {
         Object * obj = GenerateObject(-1);

         // Succeeded
         return 0;
     }
     catch (std::exception & e)
     {
         // Failed, exiting with error value
         return 1;
     } 
}
```

If an empty value is allowed, you can specify a specific value for this class, eg.

```
class Rectangle
{
private:
    int left, top, width, height;

public:
    Rectangle(l, t, w, h)
    {
        left = l;
        top = t;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public static Rectangle empty;
}

Rectangle Rectangle::empty = Rectangle(0, 0, -1, -1);

// ...

Rectangle DoSth(int i)
{
     // i < 0 is NOT considered an error here
     if (i < 0)
          return Rectangle::empty;

     // Further processing
}
```

Comment: Why not a [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception?

Comment: It's better here, I have no extensive knowledge of STL's exceptions. I'll correct that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pair an enumeration with the object type being returned. If the returned enumeration is a certain value, the object is valid, otherwise the object is in an invalid state.

```
// This is a working C++11 example.
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

enum result
{
    ok,
    out_of_range,
    some_other_error
};

class object
{
    public:
        object() {}
};

typedef std::shared_ptr< object > object_ptr;

typedef std::pair< result, object_ptr > return_type;

return_type some_function( int index )
{
    if ( index > 5 )
    {
        return return_type{ result::out_of_range, nullptr };
    }

    return return_type{ result::ok, object_ptr{ new object() } };
}

int main()
{
    return_type res = some_function( 10 );
    if ( res.first == result::ok )
    {
        // Do something with res.second
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the error
    }
}
```

I would probably just throw an exception instead.